# Cuando ejecuto un script desde la consola de mysql no me toma los caracteres acentuados

Tags: mysql, script, consola, charset

Tengo una tabla con dos campos:

```
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nombre varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

y un script con el siguiente insert:

```
INSERT INTO articulos VALUES (21,"Accesorio Derivación");
```

El script esta en un archivo de texto con codificación UTF8.

Mi problema ocurre cuando desde la consola de MySQL trato de ejecutar el script con:

```
source archivo.sql;
```

Me da el error "ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'nombre' at row 1".

Lo que hace es reemplazar la "ó" por "├│" y queda un caracter mas largo, en 21 de longitud, por eso da el error.

La base y la tabla las tengo definidas con:

```
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
```

Si ejecuto el mismo insert desde un QueryTab del Workbench funciona tomando bien los caracteres.

Como puedo tomar los caracteres correctamente desde el script y arreglar este problema ??? Inclusive agregar alguna función sobre el string en el insert como CONVERT me serviría.

Comment: En Windows en la linea de comandos escribo "mysql -h localhost -u root -p". Así ingreso a la consola.

Comment: Es la consola que proporciona mysql.

Comment: Para evitar esto, simplemente pon esto al inicio de tu script o archivo: `SET NAMES 'utf8';`, de ese modo, el charset de la consola se establecerá a `utf8`. Si te interesa que siempre tenga `utf8`, lo puedes hacer desde el archivo de configuración, [revisa el MR al respecto](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-applications.html).

Comment: funciono perfecto, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar esto, simplemente pon esto al inicio de tu script o archivo: `SET NAMES 'utf8';`, de ese modo, el charset de la consola se establecerá a `utf8`.

El script debería quedar así:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
INSERT INTO articulos VALUES (21,"Accesorio Derivación");
```

Ten en cuenta que `SET NAMES 'utf8';` se considera una consulta aparte, y si estás trabajando desde APIs como `mysqli` deberías usar multiquery.

Si te interesa que siempre tenga `utf8`, lo puedes hacer desde el archivo de configuración, llamado generalmente **`.mysql.cnf`**, agregando en él la siguiente entrada:

```
[mysql]
    default-character-set=utf8
```

De ese modo la consola tendrá siempre `utf8` como juego de caracteres, [revisa el MR al respecto](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-connection.html).

Es recomendable tener un archivo de configuración, donde, además del charset, indiques datos sensibles como nombre de usuario, contraseña, etc, así, no estás obligado a escribir en consola la contraseña (los servidores guardan logs de todo lo que se escribe en consola). Con el archivo de configuración conectarías de este modo más o menos:

```
/usr/bin/mysql --defaults-file=~/.unaCarpetaOcultaYSegura/.mysql.cnf
```

Asumiendo que en `.unaCarpetaOcultaYSegura` tienes un archivo llamado `.mysql.cnf` con tus credenciales, configuración de charset y otros. Esa carpeta tendría permisos de administrador y cuando conectes nunca estarías escribiendo tu contraseña en consola. Para más detalles sobre esto [consulta del MR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html).

Comment: funciono perfecto, muchas gracias